# Simple CSS but not working

Tags: css, less

I have an H1 inside an article element.

My h1 is styled something like this:

```
h1 {
    &:extend(.display1);

    border-bottom:solid 0.1rem @divider;
    color:@primaryText;
    margin-bottom:2.4rem;
    padding-bottom:0.7rem;
}
```

However, I only want to apply this styling when the H1 isn't inside an article. I thought it would be a simple addition to the CSS like this:

```
*:not(article) h1 {
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work for me and I've been left scratching my head. Is it possible? Have I got the syntax right? Is there something else lurking in the CSS?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's LESS but the styling isn't the issue. I could remove it and replace it with something like background-color:red;, but it's the :not that's failing to work.

Comment: try to reproduce your error using http://codepen.io/ or similar, so we can help you out with your question in a better way thanks!

Comment: It's not necessarily an error. I'm not 100% sure that its possible - all I know is it isn't ignoring the H1 css at present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the 'old fashioned way'?

```
.article h1{ /* insert styling for h1 inside article */ }

h1 { /* insert styling for h1 outside article */}
```

Please note that .article h1 takes all elements from h1. So make sure you override the different styles (e.g. with !important).

--EDIT--
If you want to use :not() I can't see something wrong with your lines of code.
How does the HTML looks like? I got this example in JSFiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2aruu0Lr/1/

It doesn't work if there is no parent tag for h1, it does if there is one like a `<span>` or in my case a `<strong>`
Hope this helps you!

Solution:

**body *:not(article) h1**

Comment: Exactly, which Is why I'd prefer to use the :not() if possible

Comment: I edited my answer, if this doesn't work could you edit your question with a HTML snippet?

Comment: Robiin - you worked it out. Article does indeed require a parent. The following code works -  body *:not(article) h1.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use this:

```
h1 {
    color:blue;
    margin-bottom:2.4rem;
    padding-bottom:0.7rem;  
}

:not(article) > h1{ 
   color: green
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvKKqE?editors=110

Answer (score 0):

Does this the trick for you?

```
@primaryText: #000000;
@divider: lime;
.display1 {
    padding: 15px;
}

h1 {
    &:extend(.display1);

    :not(article) > & {

        border-bottom:solid 0.1rem @divider;
        color:@primaryText;
        margin-bottom:2.4rem;
        padding-bottom:0.7rem;

    }
}
```

Output:

```
.display1,
h1 {
  padding: 15px;
}
:not(article) > h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 0.1rem lime;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 2.4rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
}
```